# Komma bei Umordnung eines Satzes; Commata in Reordered Sentence

Tags: comma, punctuation

Sind die Kommata in folgendem Satz richtig?

> Eine Annahme, im Hauptsatz, fehlte.

Der Satz ist im Prinzip eine Umordnung des folgenden Satzes:

> Im Hauptsatz fehlte eine Annahme.

Und dieser hat überhaupt kein Komma. Und falls die obigen Kommata richtig sind, wie heisst die (Komma-)regel dazu?

(English translation of the question): I am curious, is the comma in the follow sentence correct:

> Eine Annahme, im Hauptsatz, fehlte.

Technically, it is just a reordering of the next sentence.

> Im Hauptsatz fehlte eine Annahme.

This sentence does not has any comma at all. In case the commata are correct, is there a (comma-)rule that demands these commata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eine Annahme, im Hauptsatz, fehlte.

Wrong, it's too closely related. Make it

> Eine Annahme im Haupsatz fehlte.

Despite being a re-arrangement of

> Im Hauptsatz fehlte eine Annahme.

I wouldn't use commas here. Except if I wrote some philosophical text and the commas would emphasize an important feature, but in that case we tend to use Gedankenstrich (em-dash).

I am not that great with the commas when I write German. Not a rule-Nazi myself, and I read enough classic texts such as Goethe, Kant to Hegel, or older stuff even, where the rules are much less obsessively applied.

But to give you a rule, you hardly need commas unless you have relative clauses, and of course before "that".

> Eine Annahme, die in jeden Haupsatz gehört, fehlte.

> Er ermahnte sie, daß eine Annahme in jedem Hauptsatz fehlte.

Of course sequential commas, but only if its a real sequence

> Annahmen, Ableitungen und Übertreibungen sollten in jedem Hauptsatz vorkommen aber nicht in Nebensätzen.

I am doubtful if I should even put a comma before "aber" because the sentence after aber uses the same verb and cannot thus be separated by comma. Also, note, no comma before "und", except if it is a real new sentence with its own verb!

> Er nörgelte dauernd über fehlende Annahmen in Hauptsätzen, und damit ging er allen anderen auf die Nerven.

By the way, you can rearrange a lot, it just sounds stranger but you don't need commas:

> Er nörgelte dauernd über in Hauptsätzen fehlende Annahmen, und er ging damit allen anderen auf die Nerven.

> Dauernd nörgelte er über Hauptsätze, in denen Annahmen fehlen, ...

Here it is the use of "denen" after "in", which makes it a relative clause, so then you must use a comma.